# I don't see colors when open a C file in vim

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I dont see colors when open a C file in vim, check my terminal type using the folllowing command

```
> echo $TERM
vt100
```

Is it because vt100 doesn't supports colors. How can I change the same?

Comment: syntax on & colorscheme is already set in my .vimrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:set t_Co?` tells you what Vim thinks about the available colors. If this is empty or `2`, you obviously should try to fix the terminal type `$TERM`, either by using another terminal that gets detected properly, or by updating the variable's content (most terminals will work with a value of `xterm`, which gets you 16 colors).

Comment: I didn't get any thing by running above command in vim. :set t-Co? => t_Co =

Comment: @Karun: That means no colors, too. What about `TERM=xterm vim`, or `:set t_Co=16` within Vim, does that help?!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
:syntax on
```

<sub>Note<sup>**[1]**</sup></sub>

But it could be your version of Vim was

- compiled without support for synatx highlighting
- not packaged with the syntax definitions for C

---

<sub>Note<sup>**[1]**</sup></sub> In fact

```
 filetype plugin on
 filetype indent on
 syntax on
```

are good to have in your .vimrc

Comment: Tried this, it didnt' help either.

Answer (score 1):

type:
`:syntax on`
then
`:colorscheme` and then press `TAB` and select what you want.

Comment: Thanks but syntax on colorscheme is set in my .vimrc